# Get order on observer event

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im trying to get the order data from the observer, but is returning me null, is happening me only on the "sales_order_credit_memo_save_after", dont understang why is happening in this specific one. The event is for sure loading the right method, but in the order data gets null.

my code here.
config.xml:

```
<events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <ordertest>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>ordertest/observer</class>
                        <method>createInvoice</method>
                    </ordertest>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>

            <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <ordertest>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>ordertest/observer</class>
                        <method>createCredit</method>
                    </ordertest>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        </events>
```

Observer:

```
public function createCredit($observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
var_dump($order);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add getCreditmomo method to get the order:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getOrder();
```